# Finding prime_factors that returns the prime factors of an integer as a list

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    lst = []
    while i <= n:
        if isprime(i):
            lst.append(i)
        i += 1
    return lst
def isprime(n):
    n = isdivisor(n)
    i = 2
    lst = []
    for j in n:
        while i <= j/2:
            if j % i != 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
            i += 1
def isdivisor(n):
    i = 2
    lst = []
    while i <= n/2:
        if n % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
        i += 1
    return lst
print prime_factors(15)
```

First, I tried to find divisors of integer `n` and checked the divisors whether they are prime or not.However the output is somehow `[10, 14, 15]` instead of `[3,5]`. Is it because I can't do the assignment `n = isdivisor(n)` or something else ?

Comment: Why are you using while loops instead of for loops? What is the `isdivisor()` function for?

Comment: `isprime(4)` returns `None`, so that's not a good sign. Did you not test any of your code as you wrote it?

Comment: Work from the actual problem first, then you can worry about the results from those, later. Consider these test cases: isprime(2), isprime(5), isprime(10). Actually, isprime depends on isdivisor ... you should probably look into that first.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Insert useful output statements to trace the control and data flow.  As the posting guidelines say, "make it easy for others to help you."  We expect you to make an effort to trace your code; don't simply dump it here and tell us it gives the wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote a pice of code to do It, without using libs. I hope It can help you.

---

my code:

```
def get_square_root(n):
  """Return square root of n."""
  return n ** (1.0 / 2)


def is_divisor(n, d):
  """Return True if n divides d, False otherwise."""
  return n % d == 0


def is_prime(n):
  """Return True if n is prime, False otherwise."""
  limit = int(get_square_root(n))
  for i in range(2, limit+1):
    if is_divisor(n, i):
      return False
  return True


def get_prime_factors(n):
  """Return a list of the prime factors of n."""
  prime_factors = []
  for i in range(2, n):
    if is_divisor(n, i) and is_prime(i):
      prime_factors.append(i)
  return prime_factors


if __name__ == '__main__':
  n = 15  # Change n to test 
  prime_factors = get_prime_factors(n)
  print(prime_factors)
```

output:

```
[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some logical errors in your code. You are overcomplicating things somewhat by returning lists of divisors and primes. You already have a loop in the `prime_factors()` to go through all the numbers from 2 to `n`. So you can simplify your `isdivisor()` and `isprime()` functions:

```
def isdivisor(i, n):
    return n % i == 0

def isprime(n):
    i = 2
    while i < n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

Then change your main loop in `prime_factors()` like this:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    lst = []
    while i < n:
        if isdivisor(i, n) and isprime(i):
            lst.append(i)
        i += 1
    return lst
```

Output:

```
>>>prime_factors(15)
[3,5]
```